# How do I zoom in/out of a ChartControl contained in a parent ScrollViewer in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, devexpress

I have a ChartControl inside a Grid where there is a ScrollViewer.
I need to activate zoom on the ChartControl but when I use the mouse wheel on the ChartControl, until I reach the limit on the Grid ScrollViewer, it's the Grid ScrollViewer who is scrolling instead.

I think there is something missing inside the DevExpress control because on the native WPF control it's working. Example list view below.

```
ChartControl cc = new ChartControl();

cc.Titles.Add(new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.Title() { Content = "" });
cc.Legend = new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.Legend();

DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.XYDiagram2D xy = new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.XYDiagram2D();
xy.EnableAxisXNavigation = true;
xy.EnableAxisYNavigation = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, implement custom mouse wheel processing by handling the ScrollViewer.PreviewMouseWheel event. Check
[this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T728102/how-to-scroll-parent-scrollviewer-only-when-mouse-is-outside-the-child-chart-control) ticket for a sample project illustrating this approach (see the [DXSample.zip](https://isc.devexpress.com/Attachment/GetAttachment?fileOid=3f4bbff7-d6d3-4c19-bcc9-8b669a19c030&fileName=DxSample.zip) archive).